# Is there a way to intercept the result of Spring MVC RestController endpoint before serialization?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My Spring RestController have the following method which returns the DTO:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/profile",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public UserProfileDto getUserProfile() {...}
```

I would like intercept the controller method call, get the resulted DTO and modify some fieds before serialization into JSON?

As far as I understand there are 2 ways:

Custom filter:

Doesn't work as I can get only byte stream of serialized response

Custom HandlerInterceptor:

But I'm not sure how can I do it as postHandle in HandlerInterceptor have null ModelAndView, and afterCompletion doesn't have ModelAndView at all

Comment: Why can't you just modify the fields in the controller method before it is returned by it?

Comment: To get user_id from UserProfileDto object and if it matches some rule modify user name and save back into UserProfileDto object. **UPD**: I can, but it need to rename user in many endpoints and want to avoid copy-paste

Comment: Sorry I deleted my first comment which I think that was a response to because I read the question better. Posted a new one now

Comment: As far as I understand, I can return ModelAndView with UserProfileDto object incapsulated into it from getUserProfile() method and then "catch" it in HandlerInterceptor. It will require some refactoring. But are there other ways?

Comment: Why don't you update the result response Object POJO and update setter methods?

Other option is to decorate the result DTO and modify it in a method at Java level itself instead of using Filters or Custom marshellers/unmarshallers

Comment: Honestly in my opinion a bit of repeated code in the controller methods themselves is probably better than trying to intercept them. You could just put the repeated code in a nice helper method that is shared between your controller methods.

Comment: Use AOP around your REST controller.

Answer (score -1):

You may use [OncePerRequestFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html), like this example below,

```
    @Component
    public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
      private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

      @Autowired
      public MyFilter(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
      }

      @Override
      protected void doFilterInternal(
          final HttpServletRequest request,
          final HttpServletResponse response,
          final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Add your code here ...

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      }
    }
```

You can do this to change the handle your response,

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/profile",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<UserProfileDto> getUserProfile() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new UserProfileDto());
}
```

Comment: How can I get the object, returned by my controller in this filter?